# Contentplace holder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can we use Content place holder within the head section of a master page?

for example :

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **yes**. Is it not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ContentPlaceHolder within the head section of a master page. I'm sending you a working example, out of my project. Make sure you set the attribute runat="server" for head tag. You can also have multiple ContentPlaceHolders within the head tag. see example and enjoy :)

```
<head ID="Head1" runat="server" Visible="true">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--PageTitle_START-->

    <title>
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </title>

    <!--PageTitle_END-->

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderHeaderScripts" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </head>
```

Comment: That's great! Mark it as answer if you think it has helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the <head> tag has a runat=”server” attribute defined, a content page can programmatically add to the <head> section of an ASPX page. The following is perfectly valid:

```
<head runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" id="headerPlaceHolder" />
</head>
```

Comment: i use it on masterpage which is mypage.master.